# NgRx unsubscribe from store in effects

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a simple effect:

```
@Effect()
simpleEffect = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<ActionA>('Action A'),
  withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectSomething)),
  map(([action, something]) => console.log('CALLED TWICE'))
);
```

Here is the selector:

```
export const selectSomething = createSelector(
  (appState) => appState.someState,
  (someState) => someState.something
)
```

The following is a simple reducer which updates value of `something`:

```
export const someReducer = (state: SomeState = someInitialState, action: ActionB) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'Action B':
      return {
        ...state,
        something: action.payload
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

### The problem:

When I dispatch ActionB, the effect for ActionA is called, despite it wasn't.

As I found out, it happens because of `withLatestFrom(this.store.select(selectSomething))` in the effect, which observes any changes of `something` FOREVER.

### The question:

Is it possible to unsubscribe from that selector? Or is there other function instead of `withLatestFrom`?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in the code you showed, because [withLatestFrom](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/withlatestfrom) emit only one event.
Install [Redux DevTools](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd) to see what actions you send and see if you don't send 'Action A' twice

Answer (score 0):

The problem was similar but not the same.

Honestly, I had another effect for ActionC:

```
@Effect
otherEffect = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType<ActionC>('Action C'),
  switchMap(() => this.store.select(selectSomethingElse)),
  switchMap(() => of(new ActionA()))
)
```

And it's called when `somethingElse` had been changed.

I didn't dispatch ActionA deliberately, but `simpleEffect` was triggered by `otherEffect` which was subscribed on `selectSomethingElse`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ngrx addressed this with [version 12](https://medium.com/ngrx/announcing-ngrx-version-12-new-operator-for-effects-componentstore-enhancements-integrated-9dcb2519d495). Checkout [concatLatestFrom](https://ngrx.io/guide/effects/operators#concatlatestfrom)